# R shiny Observe running Before loading of UI and this causes Null parameters

Tags: r, shiny

I am running into an issue because observe is being called first before the UI loads.

Here is my ui.R

```
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("Desk", "Desk:" ,  as.matrix(getDesksUI())),
    uiOutput("choose_Product"), #this is dynamically created UI
    uiOutput("choose_File1"), #this is dynamically created UI
    uiOutput("choose_Term1"), #this is dynamically created UI  ....
```

Here is my Server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output,session) {

  #this is dynamic UI
  output$choose_Product <- renderUI({ 
    selectInput("Product", "Product:", as.list(getProductUI(input$Desk)))
  })

   #this is dynamic UI
  output$choose_File1 <- renderUI({
    selectInput("File1", "File 1:", as.list(getFileUI(input$Desk, input$Product)))
  })

  #this is dynamic UI and I want it to run before the Observe function so the call
  # to getTerm1UI(input$Desk, input$Product, input$File1) has non-null parameters
  output$choose_Term1 <- renderUI({
    print("Rendering UI for TERM")
    print(paste(input$Desk," ", input$Product, " ", input$File1,sep=""))
    selectInput("Term1", "Term:", getTerm1UI(input$Desk, input$Product, input$File1))
  })
```

This is my observe function and it runs before the input$Product and input$File1 are populated so I get an error because they are both NULL.  But I need to use the input from the UI.

```
   observe({ 
    print("in observe")
    print(input$Product)
    max_plots<-length(getTerm2UI(input$Desk, input$Product, input$File1))
    #max_plots<-5
            # Call renderPlot for each one. Plots are only actually generated when they
            # are visible on the web page.
            for (i in 1:max_plots )   {
              # Need local so that each item gets its own number. Without it, the value
              # of i in the renderPlot() will be the same across all instances, because
              # of when the expression is evaluated.
              local({
               my_i <- i
                plotname <- paste("plot", my_i, sep="")
                output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
                  plot(1:my_i, 1:my_i,
                       xlim = c(1, max_plots ),
                       ylim = c(1, max_plots ),
                        main = paste("1:", my_i, ". n is ", input$n, sep = "") )
                })
              })
            }##### End FoR Loop
 },priority = -1000)
```

Any idea how to get the input$Product and input$File1 to be populated BEFORE observe runs?

Thank you.

Comment: `observe` has a `priority = 0` argument. An observer with a given priority level will always execute sooner than all observers with a lower priority level. You can make priority negative if you want it to execute later. This may help.

Comment: I set the priority to -100 and nothing different happens

Answer (score 14):

**EDIT: Scroll down to TClavelle's answer for a better solution. While this answer has the most upvotes, I wrote it when Shiny had fewer features than it does today.**

The simplest way is to add an `is.null(input$Product)` check at the top of each observe, to prevent it from running before the inputs it uses are initialized.

If you don't want your observers to do the null-check each time they're run, you can also use the `suspended = TRUE` argument when registering them to prevent them from running; then write a separate observer that performs the check, and when it finds that all inputs are non-null, calls resume() on the suspended observers and suspends itself.

Comment: For others who find this in your google search, this is the easiest solution and what worked for me. It lets you stick to only `observe` functions.

Comment: Thanks. that worked well for me too..

Answer (score 12):

You can use `req()` to "require" an input before a reactive expression executes, as per the Shiny documentation here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/req.html and the function documentation here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/req.html

e.g.

```
observeEvent({
  req(input$Product)
  req(input$File1)
  # ...
})
```

Comment: This is the cleaner, more canonical way of doing it compared to the `is.null(.)` suggested in another answer.

Comment: This looks like another example of a SO top answer solving an issue, yet not in the *right* way. Using [req](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/req.html) for this, *a failure not only stops the current calculation [...] but also any callers on the call stack.* You can give all inputs as comma separated arguments as in `req(input$Product, input$File1)` as well.

Comment: @Trusky good point, edited my answer to point people toward this one.

Answer (score 11):

You need to use the [Shiny Event Handler](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/observeEvent.html) and use `observeEvent` instead of `observe`. It seems to be about the only way to get rid of the "Unhandled error" message caused by NULL values on app startup. This is so because unlike `observe` the event handler ignores NULL values by default.

So your observe function could end up looking something like this (no need for priorities, or resume/suspended etc!)

```
observeEvent(input$Product, ({

  max_plots<-length(getTerm2UI(input$Desk, input$Product, input$File1))
  ... (etc)      

  })# end of the function to be executed whenever input$Product changes
 )
```

I could not copy paste your example code easily to make it run, so I'm not entirely sure what your full observe function would look like.

Answer (score 1):

We'd need an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to provide a working answer, but, assuming you need `input$Product` and `input$File1`, but do not want to take a dependency on them, only on `input$Desk`, you could:

```
observe({ 

  product <- isolate(input$Product)
  file1 <- isolate(input$File1)

  print("in observe")
  print(product)
  max_plots<-length(getTerm2UI(input$Desk, product, file1))
  for (i in 1:max_plots )   {
    # ...
  }
})
```

this is probably effectively equivalent to an `observeEvent(input$Desk, ....)`, but might offer more flexibility.