# Priority value in reactive() like in observe() (R Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny

How do you set the priority in which `reactive()` calculations are performed in Shiny? For example, there is a `priority` option in `observe()`, quoting the help file

```
priority
    An integer or numeric that controls the priority with which this observer 
should be executed. An observer with a given priority level will always execute
sooner than all observers with a lower priority level. Positive, negative, 
and zero values are allowed.
```

I wish to apply this by having my Shiny dashboard display some summary statistics *before* writing these statistics to a logging database, here is an example

In `server.R` retrieve data every hour

```
observe({
    invalidateLater(3600000,session)
    con <- dbConnect(PostgreSQL(), ...)

    values$data = dbGetQuery(con, "select * from table;")
})

output$text = renderText({
    temp = values$data
    print(paste("the mean is", mean(temp)))
})

observe({
    temp = values$data
    dbWriteTable(con, paste0("Insert into table_means Values (", (mean(temp),");" ))
})
```

And in `ui.R` I print the mean of the data.

**I wish the rendering in the UI to occur before writing the values to my sql database**

**Here are some related questions**:

[R shiny Observe running Before loading of UI and this causes Null parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845874/r-shiny-observe-running-before-loading-of-ui-and-this-causes-null-parameters)

Comment: Can you give a basic example of what you want to observe. Reactives are evaluated lazily. Observers are evaluated eagerly hence the need for a priority.

Comment: For example, I am plotting a line of best fit using `renderPlot()`, however, I recalculate the gradient of this line in an `observe()` further on so that I can write it into a database. I would like the plot to render first so that users can see it, and then write the relevant values later on in the background.

Comment: if you want the reader to see it first, don't you need a button for the user to save if desired ?

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I have included a detailed example which I hope answers your question @StéphaneLaurent.

Answer (score 1):

I may have found the answer in this question: [R shiny passing reactive to selectInput choices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465411/r-shiny-passing-reactive-to-selectinput-choices)

**Using `outputOptions` one can do the following (pasted from the help file):

```
## Not run:
# Get the list of options for all observers within output
outputOptions(output)

# Disable suspend for output$myplot
outputOptions(output, "myplot", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)

# Change priority for output$myplot
outputOptions(output, "myplot", priority = 10)

# Get the list of options for output$myplot
outputOptions(output, "myplot")
## End(Not run)
```

So this allows you to set the priority of the output items, but it still doesn't tell me how these priorities are relative to the `observe()` priority.

Comment: actually I don't think this answer is correct as the responses to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845874/r-shiny-observe-running-before-loading-of-ui-and-this-causes-null-parameters seem to suggest that setting observer priority to a negative number does not help.