# R Shiny: How to update an input object before a reactive statement gets executed

Tags: r, shiny, scheduling

I am building an explorative visual app based on the awesome R Shiny package. One thing the app will do is to read a real-valued "measurement" column and display a boxplot of those measurement values. In addition, there is an optional `selectInput` widget that allows the user to select a **group** variable to dive into. The **group** variable basically contains the names of columns having categorical values, e.g. gender (Female vs Male), country (US, CA, and etc). So if "gender" is selected from the **group** `selectInput`, the app will display two boxplots, one for the female and the other for the male.

To give the user the flexibility of focusing on certain categories, say only the female, I came up with the `checkboxGroupInput` that is only shown when **group** variable is selected with both `choices` and `selected` being initially set to all the categories of the **group** variable. So for instance, when the user only wants to see the boxplot of the female, he/she can easily un-check the check box of the male and the boxplot of the male get removed while that of the female remains.

Following [warmoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4190526/warmoverflow)'s suggestion, here is a reproducible toy example

```
# global setup
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
set.seed(12345)
dummy_data <- data.frame(
    Value = c(rnorm(50), 2 + rnorm(50)),
    Gender = c(rep('Female', 50), rep('Male', 50)),
    Country = c(rep('US', 50), rep('CA', 50)),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# ui function
ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput('group', 'Group',
                        c('Choose'='', setdiff(names(dummy_data), 'Value'))),
            uiOutput('group_select')
        ),
        mainPanel(plotOutput('box_plot'))
    )
)

# server function
server <- function(input, output) {

    # the group level select/unselect widget
    output$group_select <- renderUI({
        req(input$group)
        data <- dummy_data
        group_levels <- unique(data[[input$group]])
        conditionalPanel(
            condition = "input.group != ''",
            checkboxGroupInput('group_select', input$group,
                               choices = group_levels, selected = group_levels)
        )
    })

    # filter the data if group variable is selected
    data_to_plot <- reactive({
        data <- dummy_data
        if(!(is.null(input$group) || input$group == '')) {
            data <- data %>% 
                mutate_(group_ = input$group) %>%
                filter(group_ %in% input$group_select)
        } else {
            data$group_ <- as.factor(rep.int(1, nrow(data)))
        }
        return(data)
    })

    # show the boxplot
    output$box_plot <- renderPlot({
        data <- data_to_plot()
        validate(
            need(!(is.null(data) || nrow(data) == 0),
                 'There are no data to plot!')
        )
        ggplot(data = data, aes(factor(group_), Value)) + geom_boxplot()
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Well, the code works but `reactive` statement runs twice unnecessarily, once when `input$group` gets updated and another when `input$group_select` gets updated as you can notice the error message "There are no data to plot!" when you select "Gender" from the **group** drop-down list. So my question is: is there a way to ensure the following execution order:

1. `input$group` is updated ->
2. `input$group_select` gets updated ->
3. `reactive` gets (re)executed with both updated `input$group` and `input$group_select`

I have spent almost an entire day searching for solution to little avail.

- It seemed that Roger Day has solved this in [Using sendInputMessage and receiveMessage to make shiny input objects reactive](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/udPfQ9o8JVY). But his method involves creating a jstree, which is totally an unfamiliar area to me and it looks like he has removed the solution from his Github.
- Another possible lead to follow is using `observeEvent` described here ([R shiny Observe running Before loading of UI and this causes Null parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845874/r-shiny-observe-running-before-loading-of-ui-and-this-causes-null-parameters)). However, `observeEvent` ignores it when you unselect one or multiple categories in `input$group_select`.

The difficulty of it as pointed out by Roger Day is that the input update functions are ordinarily not reactive and thus (based on my experiments and understanding) get executed later than reactive statements. Or if there is a way to make input update function reactive, priority value can be applied to alter the execution order in the desirable way.

Any input is greatly appreciated! Sorry for the long description!

Comment: Did you try reactiveEvent function?

Comment: Did you mean `observeEvent`? Yes, I tried filtering the data when "group_select" widget appears with `observeEvent(input$group_select, {to_keep <- ...; data <- data[to_keep, ]})`. The problem is that `observeEvent` seems to ignore the change when you unselect one or multiple categories in input$group_select. For instance, when "gender" is selected from **group** `selectInput`, "group_select" shows with both "male" and "female" checked initially. However if the users uncheck the male, data doesn't remove all the male rows.

Comment: No, I meant a very similar function - eventReactive

Comment: From shiny's help page of `eventReactive`, it seems to me `eventReactive` and `observeEvent` handles event-like expression in a similar way except `eventReactive` can return a value. Could you shed a bit more light on how to use it?

Comment: The idea would be to do all subsetting on data for a boxplot within a reactiveEvent. When the user made his choices he would need to press a button to create a plot.

Comment: It may be not a good idea though. I can' test some scenarios right now :(

Comment: Well, the real difficulty for me is how to define the appropriate event that is able to detect any change in `input$group_select`

Comment: Probably a combination of `observeEvent` and `isolate`. Could you post a reproducible example so that it is easier for others to test and help you?

Answer (score 2):

I think I have found a solution. The direction mentioned in [**UnnamedUser**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4956364/unnameduser) and [**warmoverflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4190526/warmoverflow) is right. The overall idea is to create a reactive value to represent, or more precisely speaking to monitor, the **group** categories selected by the user and to detect any changes in both **group** variable (use `observe`) and **group** variable selected categories (use `observe`) and then modify the reactive value accordingly by adding the following block of code in the `server` function.

```
# use a reactive value to represent group level selection
group_selects <- reactiveValues(value = NULL)
observe({
    input$group
    if(is.null(input$group) || input$group == '')
        group_selects$value <- NULL
    else {
        data <- dummy_data
        group_selects$value <- unique(data[[input$group]])
    }
})
observe({
    input$group_select
    group_selects$value <- input$group_select
})
```

And then use `group_selects$value` to substitute `input$group_select` in the data manipulation block

```
# filter the data if group variable is selected
data_to_plot <- reactive({
    data <- dummy_data
    if(!(is.null(input$group) || input$group == '')) {
        req(group_selects$value)                        # To prevent unnecessary re-run
        data <- data %>% 
            mutate_(group_ = input$group) %>%
            filter(group_ %in% group_selects$value)     # Replaced input$group_select
    } else {
        data$group_ <- as.factor(rep.int(1, nrow(data)))
    }
    return(data)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Try grouping both inputs into a debounce statement like so:

```
trig <- debounce(reactive({list(
    a = input$a,
    b = input$b
)}), 500)
observeEvent(trig(),{print('triggered')})
reactive({
    ins <- trig()
    #Code that does stuff goes here 
    #reference the inputs using ins$a or ins$b
})
```

You may have to tweak the timing, and if the update takes too long you may still double update.