# Method to Loop Through a List in a Shiny Reactive Render Function

Tags: r, shiny

I have generated a series of plots that I would like to loop through when generating a dynamic number of plots in a Shiny application.  In the server function I have an observe function with the following structure:

```
server = function(input, output, session) {

    <Lots of other code>

    plotlist = generate_list_of_plots()
    for(i in seq_len(length(plot list))) {
        plotname = sprintf('ui_plot_%i', i)
        output[[plotname]] = renderPlot(plotlist[[i]])
    }

    <Lots of other code>

}
```

Unfortunately, this does not function as I would like as the last plot in the list is repeated for each of the correlated plotOutput objects which were generated in a separate block of code.  I believe this behavior is related to the fact that the renderPlot expressions are not called until the plots are made visible when the user clicks on a tab and the `i` indexing variable has been advanced to its final position and is static each time the renderPlot function is executed, and therefore I get the same plot.

1: Is this the true cause of the issue?
2: If it is, what is the correct way to handle this type of situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though I was able to locate a solution to the problem.  I was correct in my assumption and the answer is the `local` function.  The solution was found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22840892/r-shiny-loop-to-display-multiple-plots) post.

The corrected code would be the following:

```
server = function(input, output, session) {

    <Lots of other code>

    plotlist = generate_list_of_plots()
    for(i in seq_len(length(plot list))) {
        local({
            my_i = i
            plotname = sprintf('ui_plot_%i', my_i)
            output[[plotname]] = renderPlot(plotlist[[my_i]])
        })
    }

    <Lots of other code>

}
```